# Cocos2d-x проброс пользовательских параметров

Tags: c++, cocos2d

Хочу прокинуть умный указатель в качестве пользовательского параметра событию.

```
std::shared_ptr<SomeObject> smartPointer = std::make_shared<SomeObject>();
EventCustom event("EVENT");
event.setUserData(smartPointer);
```

Но это невозможно, потому что метод `setUserData` в качестве параметра принимает `void*` . Чем можно воспользоваться для решения этой ситуации?

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае есть два варианта, либо использовать не `shared_ptr`, а наследника `cocos2d::Ref` и методы `retain()/release()` и передавать такой указатель через cocos2d::CustomEvent как в примере, либо делать наследника `cocos2d::Event` и там создавать член класса `std::shared_ptr<SomeType>`. Второй вариант на мой взгляд лучше, т.к. вы не играете в угадайку с типом передаваемых данных и точно знаете что в эвенте приходит.
Также можно использовать `boost::AnyValue` и его аналоги чтобы не плодить кучу однотипных эвентов.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод `get` класса `std::shared_ptr`

```
event.setUserData(smartPointer.get());
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не надо советовать людям вынимать raw-pointer из shared_ptr, тем самым вы оказываете им медвежью услугу, т.к. отправив "сырой" указатель через event создается ситуация, когда это указатель кто-то захочет подержать и в резельтате получится обращение к разрушенному объекту. В приведенном примере, если shared_ptr никуда не сохранится, будет UB.

Лучше наследовать Event и добавить ему поле под shared_ptr<someType> либо boost::AnyValue